# In ClassReader.php line 19: Class Migration\Handler\CleanMultiselect does not exist

Tags: migration, magento2.3.3

I am migrating Magento 1.9.4.5 to Magento 2.3.3.
I have followed all the mentioned steps to install and configure Data Migration tool as per the instruction in https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/migration/migration-tool-install.html.

I have successfully migrated Settings but while migrating data, i got the error

**In ClassReader.php line 19:**

```
   Class Migration\Handler\CleanMultiselect does not exist
```

and Migration stopped. [image]Check the screenshot attached

I checked and found all the customers, Categories and Products are migrated but orders are not there.
I am unable to fix this issue. Can anyone help me for the same

Answer (score 0):

can you please check if the file CleanMultiselect.php is present in magento-root/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/src/Migration/Handler/ location. if not present then add according to your data-migration-tool version.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you've downloaded the correct version of Data Migration Tool:

```
1. php bin/magento --version [Output: Magento CLI 2.3.3]
2. composer https://repo.magento.com composer require
3. magento/data-migration-tool:2.3.3
```

`Class Migration\Handler\CleanMultiselect` is exists in the [Data Migration Tool](https://github.com/magento/data-migration-tool/blob/2.3/src/Migration/Handler/CleanMultiselect.php)